# Series involving squares of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Does anyone know if this sum has a closed form formula ?
$$\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k\\
 n\in N$$

Comment: [yes](https://tinyurl.com/yc8d3hhl)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That just shifts the burden to calculating a closed form of the Legendre polynomials and they're of the form $P_n(x)= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (x-1)^{n-k}(x+1)^k$ which would be a similar computation.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That's right, but I think it's as close to a closed form as one can expect.